# Windows domain account can't create files via samba share, but can do this in linux shell, why?

Tags: permissions, samba, acl

I'm migrating [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) server from windows to linux (CentOS 6.3 64bit), and want to use [samba](http://www.samba.org) to share tomcat directory to technical department staffs (windows domain users) with read+write rights.

I've setup kerberos & winbind & samba successfully, and did the following permission settings:

```
# add some domain users to local 'tech' group
group add --gid 777 tech
groupmems --group tech --add liu.yan
groupmems --group tech --add MY-DOMAIN\\liu.yan

# change owner & mode of tomcat directory
chown tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
chmod 6755 /var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
cd /var/lib
ln -s apache-tomcat-6.0.35 tomcat6

# add ACL entry
setfacl --modify group:tech:rwx /var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
```

**Check permission setting, and use windows domain user account create file/directory -- successfully**

```
[root@webserver apache-tomcat-6.0.35]# pwd
/var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.35

[root@webserver apache-tomcat-6.0.35]# getfacl /var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/
# owner: tomcat
# group: tomcat
# flags: ss-
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:tech:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x

[root@webserver apache-tomcat-6.0.35]# su liu.yan
[liu.yan@webserver apache-tomcat-6.0.35]$ mkdir temp-dir
[liu.yan@webserver apache-tomcat-6.0.35]$ touch temp-file.txt
[liu.yan@webserver apache-tomcat-6.0.35]$ getfacl temp-*
# file: temp-dir
# owner: liu.yan
# group: tomcat
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# file: temp-file.txt
# owner: liu.yan
# group: tomcat
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

**Create file/directory via samba share -- failed**

```
[root@webserver apache-tomcat-6.0.35]# smbclient -U liu.yan //localhost/tomcat6
Enter liu.yan's password:
Domain=[MY-DOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-125.el6]

smb: \> mkdir temp-dir2-via-samba-share
NT_STATUS_MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECTED making remote directory \temp-dir2-via-samba-share
```

If I changed the mode of /var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/ directory to `777`, then I CAN create file/directory in samba share on Windows clients, but CAN NOT do this via `smbclient` tool.

Why ?

**[tomcat6] share setting in smb.conf**

```
[tomcat6]
    comment = Tomcat 6
    path = /var/lib/tomcat6
    public =yes
    write list = root,@tomcat,@tech
```